# ActiveRecord select does not create accessor method when relation is ordered by attribute of joined model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am using Ruby 2.1, Rails 4.2, and mysql2 (0.4.4). My app has the following 2 models:

```
class Batch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :batch_type
end

class BatchType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :batches
end
```

Created with the following migrations:

```
class CreateBatches < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :batches do |t|
      t.integer :batch_type_id
      t.string :title

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateBatchTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :batch_types do |t|
      t.string :short_name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I seeded the database with the following:

```
BatchType.create short_name: 'Type 1'
Batch.create batch_type: BatchType.first
```

I am trying to use a dynamically created attribute accessor named 'duration', which is the difference between the timestamps for `created_at` and `updated_at`. The accessor is available when I order the result by the `title` attribute:

```
2.1.0 :007 >   Batch.order('title').select('batches.*', 'IF(batches.updated_at AND batches.created_at, batches.updated_at - batches.created_at, 0) AS duration').includes(:batch_type).first.duration
  Batch Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  batches.*, IF(batches.updated_at AND batches.created_at, batches.updated_at - batches.created_at, 0) AS duration FROM `batches`  ORDER BY title LIMIT 1
  BatchType Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `batch_types`.* FROM `batch_types` WHERE `batch_types`.`id` IN (1)
 => 0
```

But the accessor is not available when I order the result by an attribute on the joined model `BatchType`:

```
2.1.0 :008 > Batch.order('batch_types.short_name').select('batches.*', 'IF(batches.updated_at AND batches.created_at, batches.updated_at - batches.created_at, 0) AS duration').includes(:batch_type).first.duration
  SQL (0.6ms)  SELECT  batches.*, IF(batches.updated_at AND batches.created_at, batches.updated_at - batches.created_at, 0) AS duration, `batches`.`id` AS t0_r0, `batches`.`batch_type_id` AS t0_r1, `batches`.`batch_status_id` AS t0_r2, `batches`.`title` AS t0_r3, `batches`.`created_at` AS t0_r4, `batches`.`updated_at` AS t0_r5, `batch_types`.`id` AS t1_r0, `batch_types`.`short_name` AS t1_r1, `batch_types`.`created_at` AS t1_r2, `batch_types`.`updated_at` AS t1_r3 FROM `batches` LEFT OUTER JOIN `batch_types` ON `batch_types`.`id` = `batches`.`batch_type_id`  ORDER BY batch_types.short_name LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `duration' for #<Batch:0x0000010125ede0>
```

How is the order of the result affecting the creation of accessors by `select`?

Comment: How are dynamically creating a dynamic accessor?

Comment: In short, 'Rails magic' :) It's covered in this documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select - "If an alias was specified, it will be accessible from the resulting objects"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're abusing [`includes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) a bit. `includes` is intended to mash several tables together into one query to reduce the number of queries you need to do. If you just want to JOIN then use [`joins`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins):

```
Batch.order('title')
     .select('batches.*', 'IF(batches.updated_at AND batches.created_at, batches.updated_at - batches.created_at, 0) AS duration')
     .joins(:batch_type)
     .first
     .duration
```

Alternatively, add a method to `Batch` that calculates the duration in Ruby and keep using `includes`:

```
class Batch < ActiveRecord::Base
  def duration
    updated_at - created_at
  end
  #...
end
```

I haven't been able to find a way to make `select`, `includes`, and `order` work together they way you need them too, sorry.

---

Here comes a bit of hand waving and conjecture. You'd need to dig through the ActiveRecord source to figure what is really going on that is a very non-trivial task, there be dragons and other fearsome beasts.

The generated `t0_r0` ... column names in the SELECT are probably at the root of the problem:

```
SELECT batches.*,
       IF(batches.updated_at AND batches.created_at, batches.updated_at - batches.created_at, 0) AS duration,
       `batches`.`id` AS t0_r0, ...
       `batch_types`.`id` AS t1_r0, ...
```

When you use [`includes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes), you're telling ActiveRecord that you want it to do one query with everything mashed together (hence the LEFT JOIN and funny looking `tN_rM` column aliases you see in the SQL) and then ActiveRecord has to pull all the different models out of the combined query. Along the way it probably forgets about your `select` completely because it has to build its own SELECT clause in a very specific format; there's a conflict here: calling `select` tells AR to look at the SELECT to figure out what the query returns and what methods should be available on the model instances, calling `includes` tells AR to build its own SELECT.

In your first query:

```
Batch.order('title')...
```

AR isn't forced to do a JOIN so it doesn't do one and your SELECT gets through the bowels of ActiveRecord unscathed. In your second query:

```
Batch.order('batch_types.short_name')...
```

AR is forced to do a JOIN and that activates the SELECT mangling logic that sends everything sideways.

`includes` is a bit of a hack so it isn't surprising that it is a little fragile.

I'd call this a bug in AR, it should either complain that you're confusing its little mind with your `select` call or it should do it right.

Comment: Thanks! I just got around to trying 'joins' in place of 'includes' and that solved my problem. I still have the problem that my understanding of the difference between 'includes' and 'joins' is a little shaky, but I'll read up on that. I was just using 'includes' because that's what was being used in the existing code when I started to implement sorting. "It was on fire when I got here".

Comment: Executive summary: use `includes` when you want to avoid multiple queries to satisfy relations, use `joins` when you want to access multiple tables in a single query. If you put enough gasoline on a fire, it will go out, maybe.